# React-native firebase deeplinking app in background

Tags: firebase, react-native, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am implementing an app that allows you to create an account only by using a link that you get via email. Everything works fine when the app is closed using `getInitialLink()`.
The problem is when the app is in the background I failed to find a way.

I tried using `onLink()` making it listen to the general form of the dynamic link `domain.page.link` but it doesn't work. The link that i get from this function is the general form of the link, not the link on the email which is something like `domain.page.link/code=#somecode`.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction at the [React Native doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#handling-deep-links) about deep linking.

Two functions need to be added in AppDelegate.m for this to work.

```
// iOS 9.x or newer
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
```

Cheers